# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CompPlanTypeId'

Tags: html, .net, viewbag

I'm stuck on why this is is erroring out.
If i remove the div tag that holds the Comp Plan:, it works just fine.

```
<div id="tabs-1"> 
    <form id="importForm">
        <div id="required">
            <div>
                <label class="OptionLabel">Comp Plan:</label>
                @*// TODO: suspect this next line is causing problems*@ 
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompPlanTypeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompPlanList)
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="OptionLabel">System:</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SystemId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SystemList)
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="OptionLabel">Month:</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, (SelectList)ViewBag.MonthList)
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="OptionLabel">Year:</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, (SelectList)ViewBag.YearList)
            </div>
        </div>
```

in here:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = Text.Import;
        ViewBag.MonthList = MonthList;
        ViewBag.YearList = YearList;
        ViewBag.SystemList = GetSystemList();
        ViewBag.CompPlanList = GetCompPlanList();
        ViewBag.Message = "";
        ViewBag.MessageType = "";
        return View();
    }
```

ViewBag.CompPlanList is set to 2 items. One containing a blank string, one containing a drop down value.

Here's the stack trace.

```
[InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CompPlanTypeId'.]
```

System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.GetSelectData(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String name) +392896
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList) +60
   ASP._Page_Views_Import_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\WIP\CompensationAudit\src\WebLibrary\Views\Import\Index.cshtml:28